# Generating isotropic steps with lengths distributed as exp(-x/lambda)

Tags: python, function, random, montecarlo

I'm writing a code about radiation transportation and have generated isotropic vectors as shown by my code. I'm now unsure about how to generate isotropic steps with lengths distributed as exp(-x/lambda). Any suggestions?

```
def isotropic_unit_vectors():
nparticles = 1000
lambda_a = 45
lambda_s = 0.3

sigma_a = 1/lambda_a
sigma_s = 1/lambda_s
sigma_T = sigma_a + sigma_s

lambda_T = 1/sigma_T
u = np.random.uniform(low = 0, high =1, size = 1000)
step = -lambda_T*np.log(u)
theta = 2*np.pi*np.random.rand(nparticles)
phi = np.arccos(2*np.random.rand(nparticles)-1)

dx = step*np.cos(theta)*np.cos(phi)
dy = step*np.cos(theta)*np.sin(phi)
dz = step*np.sin(theta)

rand = np.column_stack((dx,dy,dz))
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(dx, dy, dz, c='r', marker='.')

ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')
plt.show()
return rand
```

edit: I want multiple particles to start at 0,0,0 then move randomly.

Comment: But you already have step length properly generated as `u = np.random.uniform(low = 0, high =1, size = 1000);
step = -lambda_T*np.log(u)` What is the problem?

Comment: I think I'm a little confused. That part makes sense, but then I want x,y,z,(0) at 0,0,0 then to be 'moving' randomly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you have right bits and pieces, but they are not quite right together. Here what it might look like, Python 3.7, Anaconda WIndows 10 x64

```
import numpy as np

def isotropic_unit_vectors():
    """Generates troika of directional cosines isotropically on the sphere"""

    cs_theta = 2.0 * np.random.random() - 1.0
    sn_theta = np.sqrt((1.0 - cs_theta)*(1.0 + cs_theta))
    phi      = 2.0 * np.pi * np.random.random()

    wx = sn_theta * np.cos(phi)
    wy = sn_theta * np.sin(phi)
    wz = cs_theta

    return (wx, wy, wz)

def random_step(λ):
    u = 1.0 - np.random.random() # NB! avoids log(0)
    return -λ * np.log(u)

nparticles = 100

λ_a = 45   # absorbtion
λ_s = 0.3  # scattering

# cross-sections
σ_a = 1/λ_a
σ_s = 1/λ_s
σ_t = σ_a + σ_s

λ_t = 1/σ_t

trajectories = {} # dictionary for all trajectories

for k in range(0, nparticles):

    trajectory = []

    # initialize particle position
    x = 0.0
    y = 0.0
    z = 0.0

    print(f"Partile number {k+1}")
    print(f"    Position {x}, {y}, {z}")

    trajectory.append((x, y, z))

    while True:
        (wx, wy, wz) = isotropic_unit_vectors() # sample direction

        step = random_step(λ_t)

        # make step and find new position
        x += wx * step
        y += wy * step
        z += wz * step

        print(f"    Position {x}, {y}, {z}")

        trajectory.append((x, y, z))

        # simulate absorbtion
        if np.random.random() < σ_a/σ_t:
            trajectories[k] = trajectory
            break # absorbtion, end of trajectory, next particle would be tracked
        else:
            pass # scattering, continue with this trajectory
```

Note, code is NOT vectorized, could be made better and faster with NumPy vectors.

UPDATE

Added code to keep all trajectories in the dictionary indexed by #. Trajectory itself is list of tuples, each tuple contains 3 coordinates of the walk

UPDATE II

If you add code after you got trajectories dictionary, it will plot one trajectory with vertices. Vertix color is defined by distance from (0,0,0).

```
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

# Data for a three-dimensional line
k = 7 # print particle #8    

trj = trajectories[k]

xline = [x for x, y, z in trj]
yline = [y for x, y, z in trj]
zline = [z for x, y, z in trj]

# plot trajectory
ax.plot3D(xline, yline, zline, 'gray')

# plot vertices
xpts = [x for x, y, z in trj]
ypts = [y for x, y, z in trj]
zpts = [z for x, y, z in trj]
rpts = [np.sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z) for x, y, z in trj]

ax.scatter3D(xpts, ypts, zpts, c=rpts, cmap='hsv')

plt.show()
```

Comment: I'm a little unsure of how to write each new x,y,z to a table for each particle. I need to use it to plot a graph to show a random walk.

Comment: @KatieP Please check update, I added code to store trajectories, it is not tested

Comment: So that makes an array of the steps but I think it 're - appends' over the initial conditions x,y,z = 0.

Comment: @KatieP no, it doesn't. I added plotting code to check if it looks ok

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to generate random number with CDF; F(x) = exp(-x/lambda), for valid support of x such that 0 <= F(x) <= 1.

**Fact:**
CDF of any random number is uniformly distributed as uniform(0,1) (the CDF Inverse method). That is, generate a uniform(0,1) random number and set it equal to the CDF, written in terms of x. Then solve for x (See step 2).

**Method**
You can follow a process as follows:

1. Generate a random number uniformly between (0, 1), let's call is u1.
2. Set u1 = exp(-x/lambda) => x = -lambda*log(u1)
3. Save x in a list or something.
4. Go back to step 1 until desired number of random numbers are generated.

**Note:** 
If exp(-x/lambda) is the PDF and not the CDF, you can find the CDF by integrating the PDF and do the same steps above, with a change in step 2, depending on what the CDF is. For step 1, you can generate a unif(0,1) in Py using `random.random()`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, there is already code which does exactly right thing: u = np.random.uniform(low = 0, high =1, size = 1000);
step = -lambda_T*np.log(u). So exponential sampling looks ok as it is.

Comment: I have this in a previous function:...     for i in range (20):
        u = np.random.uniform(low = 0, high = 1, size = 10**7)
        lamda = 45
        length = -lamda*np.log(u)                                                                                               I want x,y,z(0) at 0,0,0, then steps with lengths distributed as exp(x/lamba).    Not sure if this makes sense but thank you for the help!

Comment: Ah I see. So initially you are at (0,0,0) and then you want to take steps which are follow the distribution? Should the steps be of the same length along x, y and z? If not, are the steps in the three directions independent of each other?

Comment: Yes. The step lengths should follow the distribution but x,y,z do not need to be the same. They will be combined to give unit vector(s) r.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def isotropic_step_generator(l, size):
    # l is the attenuation length (it's the l in the distribution exp(-x/l))
    
    theta = theta = np.arccos(1-2*np.random.uniform(0, 1, size))
    phi = np.random.uniform(0, 2*np.pi, size)
    radius = -l * np.log(np.random.uniform(size=size))
    
    x = radius * np.sin(theta) * np.cos(phi)
    y = radius * np.sin(theta) * np.sin(phi)
    z = radius * np.cos(theta)
    
    return x, y, z

empty_array = np.empty((1000,3))

i=0
while i<1000:
    empty_array[i] = isotropic_step_generator(45, 1) # attenuation length for water is 45 cm
    i+=1

x_array = empty_array[:, 0]
y_array = empty_array[:, 1]
z_array = empty_array[:, 2]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.scatter(x_array, y_array, z_array, s=7)
plt.show()
```

The above code generates isotropic steps with lengths distributed as exp(-x/lambda) and plots them for water. Note that you must use arccos for theta to prevent bunching of points towards the poles.